# Django-CMS sometimes cannot publish a page

Tags: django, django-cms, django-mptt

I have a site in Django-CMS 2.4.1.  I often go into the admin panel and change a page there, e.g. dragging a plugin from one placeholder to another, or just change the details of a plugin.

If I press "Publish draft" straight after this, I often get an error:

`PublicIsUnmodifiable: The public instance cannot be published. Use draft.`

Alternatively, sometimes I am told that I cannot submit the form as the slug is already taken (by the same page).

I have found that if I navigate away, come back, make the changes again, and press "Save and continue editing", and only then "Publish draft", it often works - but not always.

Also, I have found that I often cannot delete plugins from pages.

Has this happened to anyone else? Has my database somehow become corrupted?

Sorry I can't be more specific, but I thought I'd ask in case others have had the same problem. I am still trying to work out the pattern. The new management command `cms check` doesn't detect anything wrong.

One thought - I am using `mptt` version 0.5.5, which is higher than that loaded automatically by Django-CMS (which uses 0.5.2).

Comment: my guess would be the mptt version mismatch. why do you not use 0.5.2?  If that's not the problem, this sounds like a bug so I suggest you report it here: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues

Comment: I was using 0.5.5 as I found that stopped the deprecation warning (`CMSPlugin.tree will be removed`). I have moved back to mptt 0.5.2 now and I still have the problem.  I can raise it as an issue but should I try and pin it down a bit further first?

Comment: The warnings are not bad per se. Open an issue so this is on our radar and then try to pin it down further